# How can I change the displayname of a variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, rename

I am looking for a way to change the display name of a variable in `ggplot2` without needing to pay attention to where this variable is used. I best illustrate my question in code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# this works, plotting hwy over year
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) + geom_point())

# now I want to show hwy as High way$, so I need to check where I use hwy,
# find the corresponding label/guide/..., and change that:
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) + geom_point() + labs(y = "Hi way$"))

# now I want to plot cty instead of hwy - that's easy to do:
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = cty)) + geom_point() + labs(y = "Hi way$"))
# oops, I forgot to change the label! that's bad!

# what I would like is to avoid mistakes like this by being able to change default
# labels based on the original variable, not based on the aesthetics to which this
# variable is assigned.

# this way, I could change y = hwy to y = cty in aes, but hwy = "Hi way$" would
# not lead to an incorrect labeling if forgotten:
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) + geom_point() + ren(hwy = "Hi way$"))
```

Is this something that exists? If not, would this be valuable addition? Note that the display name can be such that it is not a good identifier to use in code, so I would like to avoid changing the `colnames` of the original data frame.

Comment: Why Find and replace all would not work in your case? It is present in many editors.

Comment: @RonakShah because finding and replacing `hwy` by `cty` leads to the exact problem that I am describing in my example: "Hi way$" does not contain "hwy".

Comment: @RonakShah also, a second issue I have with the current state is that if you use the same variable multiple times in a plot (simplest case, `aes(x = hwy, y = hwy)`), you need to add the label multiple times. With my proposed solution, `ren(hwy = "Hi way$")`, you would not have to do that, you would do it in one single place.

Comment: Another argument, look at the amount of questions on SO, Google etc., where people basically ask "how can I modify the label when my variable is used in such and such an aesthetics", and the answer vary depending on which aesthetics it is. My approach would give the same answer to all these questions.

Comment: Have a look at the `ggeasy` package. See https://github.com/jonocarroll/ggeasy. There is a helper function `easy_labs` which could achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @stefan I had to google what a "column label attribute" is, but that looks promising - thank you! For reference, here's the documentation of the `easy_labs` function: https://jonocarroll.github.io/ggeasy/reference/easy_labs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer based on @stefan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519018/how-can-i-change-the-displayname-of-a-variable-in-ggplot/63520573#comment112320599_63519018):

```
library(ggplot2)
Hmisc::label(mpg$hwy) <- "Hi way$"
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) + geom_point() + ggeasy::easy_labs())
```

This one has the downside that it issues a warning

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type labelled/integer. Defaulting to continuous.

which is because labeling `mpg$hwy` converts the column from the original type (e.g. `"integer"`) to `c("labelled", "integer")`, and not all components of ggplot seem to know what to do with this. This may not be a problem in more complex plots  that define the scales anyway, but I might file an issue with `ggplot` about this.

**Edit:** This one also works:

```
library(ggplot2)
attr(mpg$hwy, "label") <- "Hi way$"
print(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) + geom_point() + ggeasy::easy_labs())
```

Lovely!

Answer (score 1):

I've never had this issue because when I care about nice labels, the plot is carefully optimized and unique anyway.

I suggest this approach:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_var <- "hwy"
my_lab <- "Hi way$"

print(ggplot(mpg, aes_string(x = "year", y = my_var)) + 
        geom_point() + labs(y = my_lab))
```